# Question about how a Bluetooth signal propagates out of the antenna of a BBC Microbit?

Tags: rf, antenna, wireless, bluetooth, pcb-antenna

I want to know how a Bluetooth signal propagates to which designated direction in these two pictures with the strongest output from the trace antenna.

Is there any HFSS analysis image similar to this type of trace antenna?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am science teacher. I am working on a Microbit Bluetooth proximity sensing project, so I want to get accurate information about this to tell my students.

Comment: For proximity sensing there’s two antennas involved. It’s very difficult to get anywhere near accurate distance measurement.

Comment: The antenna performance is highly dependent on the actual pcb layout, so unless the designers have measured it you have little to go on. The generic radiation pattern might get you in the ballpark but maybe you should set the task for your students to map it out and see if they all correlate?

Comment: Thanks! The experiments tells me that 'direction 5' might have the strongest output, two Microbit face each other with 'direction 5' can communicate up around 35 meters. However, after I watched some videos about antenna on Youtube. It seems that this a polarized trace antenna. Then, my conclusion is that 'direction 2' and 'direction 3' have the strongest ouput, which does not comply with my experiment results.